# User-level bundler Gemfile

Tags: bundler

I'd love to have a Gemfile in Bundler that just sets my own personal Gemfiles to always be bult into bundles...

aka ruby-debug, interactive-editor, and so forth.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create different evnironments

```
group :scott do 
end
```

Then

bundle --with-env=scott

Answer (score 3):

We use this technique.
Puth this in your Gemfile:

```
eval File.read(File.expand_path("Gemfile.personal")) if File.exists?(File.expand_path("Gemfile.personal"))
```

And then add your personal gems to Gemfile.personal. Of course exclude Gemfile.personal from your version control.

Comment: Yes it is. So we include our gemfile.lock file in .gitignore. Some people argue this is a bad practice but some people can go argue elsewhere.

Comment: well, do you at least understand the reasons as to why the gemfile.lock is recommended to stay in there?   core teams (bundler and rails) usually don't recommend stuff for no good reason...

Comment: I do understand their reasons. But in all my work there was only one case when dependency versions caused problems, but that was fixed fast and easily. So we use Gemfile.personal and do not commit .lock and everyone is happy.

Comment: you can also just ignore the locally modified Gemfile.lock temporarily by running `git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile.lock` and when you're ready to commit local changes, you can run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Gemfile.lock`. this trick just "lies" to git so that git will ignore these files for any status/commit calculations

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what it is you are trying to achieve, but;

If you just want to specify a number of development-only gems, you can specify a development group that can be excluded from deployments:

```
group :development do
  gem "ruby-debug"
  gem "interactive-editor"
end
```

Then on production or test you would do:

```
bundle install --without development
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution I found so far is to use a separate `Gemfile.personal` and use a custom `Gemfile` path. I like this solution because you can use it in any project without modifying project code at all.

#### 1. Add `Gemfile.personal` in to project root dir

```rb
# /path/to/your_ruby_project/Gemfile.personal
eval File.read('Gemfile') # use all gems from Gemfile

gem 'personal-gem1'
gem 'personal-gem2'
```

#### 2. Install gems using `Gemfile.personal` file

```sh
BUNDLE_GEMFILE="Gemfile.personal" bundle install
# or
bundle install --gemfile=Gemfile.personal
```

Just remember to specify `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` every time you execute commands with bundler.

I personally put `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.personal` env variable in `.env` file using [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which ensures that `Gemfile.personal` is always used when I execute any command with `bundler` so I do not need to put it manually every time.

#### 3. Put `Gemfile.personal` and `Gemfile.personal.lock` to `.gitignore`

For linux users:

```sh
touch ~/.gitignore
echo "Gemfile.personal\nGemfile.personal.lock" >> ~/.gitignore
```

This will affect all projects, so you do not need to update each project `.gitignore` separately.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition does not depend on Bundler.  As such does not clutter `Gemfile*` with your private gems for the price being a bit less convenient than answer by @ScottSchulthess.

#### How Bundler works

There is an array stored in `$LOAD_PATH` global variable which is a "load path for scripts and binary modules by load or require" (see [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html)) and Bundler modifies this array.

If you're developing a gem, `$LOAD_PATH` it will contain paths to all gems in the system.  You can simply write e.g. `require "pry"` somewhere and pry gem will be loaded properly even if it's not mentioned in gemspec nor Gemfile.  You don't have to add it to dependencies.  (Of course it has to be already installed with `gem install pry`.)

A very different strategy Bundler takes when you're developing an application.  In such case most of `$LOAD_PATH` will be removed on `require bundler/setup` (Rails calls it in `config/boot.rb`). Only essential paths and those pointing to gems specified in `Gemfile.lock` will remain there.  So if you want to use `pry` without adding it to Gemfile, you got to append it to `$LOAD_PATH` before requiring it.

#### Solution for applications

```
gems_root = $LOAD_PATH.detect{ |p| %r{/bundler-} =~ p}.sub(%r{/bundler-.*}, "")

additional_gems = {
  "pry" => "pry-0.10.1/lib",
  "pry-rails" => "pry-rails-0.3.2/lib",
}

load_paths = additional_gems.values.map{ |p| File.join gems_root, p }
$LOAD_PATH.unshift *load_paths
additional_gems.keys.each{ |r| require r }
```

If you're using Rails, then save it in `/config/initializers/00_custom_gems.rb` and that's all.  Outside Rails you additionally need to require it, preferably right after `require "bundler/setup"`:

```
require "path/to/it" if File.exists? "path/to/it"
```

Remember to mention this file in `.gitignore`.

Sometimes proper gem path does not end with `/lib` but with architecture name.  The easiest way to learn it is to add it for a moment to Gemfile and do `puts $LOAD_PATH` in aforementioned initializer.  You can also learn those dirs from gemspec.

#### Solution for gems

When developing gem, you don't need to enhance `$LOAD_PATH`, only to require gems you want.  If you need custom gems in tests and you're using RSpec, it can be done somewhere in `/spec/support`.

Another (less sane) idea is to add a file `lib/development.rb`:

```
require_relative "my_gem_name"
require "path/to/private/requires" if File.exists? "path/to/private/requires"
```

and refer to this file instead of to "my_gem_name" in your tests, demo application etc..